# Parsing a search result from a webpage and extracting it into a .csv or .txt file

Tags: javascript, html, database, csv

I was not able to find any topics related to my inquiry, so here goes...

I'd like to know how i can parse a webpage that displays a very long list or a big tabular data such as a list of results from a searching directories like yelp. etc. then save the extracted data into a .csv or .txt file. I was thinking like targeting specific html tags (i.e if enclosed in li in lists or td/tr in tables then copy it, but the tags can be different as different websites have
different methods of displaying info.).

I'd appreciate if anyone in this community can point me to a right direction, like a known software or code that can do such tasks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll basically need to know the structure of the website you're parsing beforehand if you want to fully automate this. You would need alot of logic to determine what to get from the page, if you don't know in advance what will be on that page.

If you make a list of all websites that you want to be able to parse, you can write specifics for each site.